# ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet Application Template OAuth RegisterGoogleClient Unsuccessful

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

I created a Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet Application Template project. I immediately went into the AuthConfig class and uncommented this line:

```
        //AuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();
```

I then ran the application. I clicked 'Log in', then 'Google'. I am redirected to Google where I sign in and then get redirect to the 'ExternalLoginCallback' action in the Account controller. In the debugger these line get executed:

```
        AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        if (!result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }
```

No matter what I do the results variable's IsSuccessful property is set to false. I am just wondering what I am doing incorrectly considering I am using the provided template? I have no idea how I can retrieve an error messages from OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication to determine what is going on.

Any help is appreciated!

Note: I have tried updating all NuGet packages. I've also tried Microsoft (didn't work because a redirect url + localhost issue) and LinkedIn (didn't work, unsure why but receiving bad request 400 error) OAuth Clients.

Comment: Did you supply an API key?

Comment: No, there is no parameter for that in the AuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient() method. However, I did supply an api key for Microsoft/linked in clients

Answer (score 2):

I found a Google OAuth2 implementation that I was able to easily get working:

https://github.com/mj1856/DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2